# div between floats works in Firefox, but not in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

This is an excerpt from a much more complex problem, but the issue comes down to this: the code works on FF43, but not on IE11. After two days, I have determined that you can get the FF output to look like the IE output by reducing the width of the outer wrapper. I've tried variants on position, float, display, etc., all to no avail.

The goal was, as the content grows, to get the content div to resize horizontally first (expanding all the wrappers), and then to resize the content div vertically when the outer width limits are reached. Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<style>
.wrapper { xwidth:480px; border:1px solid violet; }
.formbox { display: inline-block; font-family: Verdana,Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; background: #FFFFFF; border:1px solid black; }
.row { display: block; border: 1px solid #ccc; margin:3px; padding:4px; clear:both; position:relative; }
.label { float:left; display:inline-block; width:120px; text-align:right; padding-right:4px; border:1px solid red; }
.icons { float:right; width:40px; border:1px solid red; text-align:center;  }
.input { display:inline-block; border: 1px solid green; }
</style>

<div class="wrapper">

<div class="formbox">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Label:</div>
    <div class="icons">XX</div>
    <div class="input">really long wide content really long wide content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Label:</div>
    <div class="icons">XX</div>
    <div class="input">really long wide content really long wide content</div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Label:</div>
    <div class="icons">XX</div>
    <div class="input">really long wide content really long wide content</div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Label:</div>
    <div class="icons">XX</div>
    <div class="input">really long wide content really long wide content</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/des2016/r7x6d2tw/

Comment: Can you get rid of all of the floats and use `flex-box`?

Comment: not familiar with flex yet. how would you do that?

Comment: Flex will not work for this. Wrong type of thing. Please read the description more carefully. The code works perfectly on safari, opera, and chrome, too. Only IE breaks. Tried old IE6 fixes, no joy. Got to be something weird about IE ...

Comment: Ok. IE document mode to 5 or 7 fixes it. Now... what's the difference?

Comment: So, no one has a clue? So much for the experts...